Delphi 11 Mormot AES OFB (TAESOFB) Encrypt/Decrypt error
I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt a string (TBytes actually) using Mormot AES OFB (TAESOFB object) in Delphi 11.
The key is 256 bytes and IV is hardcoded as TBytes.
x64 application.
When I try to encrypt, I get a different ciphertext every time I start the program.
It's the same thing when trying to decrypt ciphertext.
That is, I can encrypt and decrypt a string while the program is running, but when I try to run the program again, the previously encrypted text is not decrypted.
What is my mistake?
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
program aes_both;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
uses
  SysUtils, Classes,
  SynCrypto,
  SynCommons;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function BytesToHex(const Bytes:TBytes):string;
const
    HexSymbols='0123456789ABCDEF';
var
    i:integer;
begin
    Result:='';
    for i := 0 to Length(Bytes)-1 do
        begin
            Result:=Result+HexSymbols[(Bytes[I] shr 4)+1];
            Result:=Result+HexSymbols[(Bytes[I] and $0F)+1];
        end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure EncryptStream(const InputStream, OutputStream: TMemoryStream; const Key, IV: TBytes);
var
  AES: TAESOFB;
  PlainText, CipherText: TBytes;
begin
  // Создание объекта AES в режиме OFB
  AES := TAESOFB.Create(Key, Length(Key) * 8);
  try
    // Установка IV
    AES.IV := PHash128(@IV[0])^;
    // Чтение данных из InputStream в массив байтов
    SetLength(PlainText, InputStream.Size);
    InputStream.Position := 0;
    InputStream.ReadBuffer(PlainText[0], InputStream.Size);
    // Шифрование
    SetLength(CipherText, Length(PlainText));
    AES.Encrypt(@PlainText[0], @CipherText[0], Length(PlainText));
    Writeln(BytesToHex(CipherText));
    // Запись зашифрованных данных в OutputStream
    OutputStream.Size := 0;
    OutputStream.WriteBuffer(CipherText[0], Length(CipherText));
    OutputStream.SaveToFile('Z:\_OUT\Dump\e.txt');
  finally
    AES.Free;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure DecryptStream(const InputStream, OutputStream: TMemoryStream; const Key, IV: TBytes);
var
  AES: TAESOFB;
  CipherText, DecryptedText: TBytes;
begin
  // Создание объекта AES в режиме OFB
  AES := TAESOFB.Create(Key, Length(Key) * 8);
  try
    // Установка IV
    AES.IV := PHash128(@IV[0])^;
    // Чтение данных из InputStream в массив байтов
    SetLength(CipherText, InputStream.Size);
    InputStream.Position := 0;
    InputStream.ReadBuffer(CipherText[0], InputStream.Size);
    // Расшифровка
    SetLength(DecryptedText, Length(CipherText));
    AES.Decrypt(@CipherText[0], @DecryptedText[0], Length(CipherText));
    // Запись расшифрованных данных в OutputStream
    OutputStream.Size := 0;
    OutputStream.WriteBuffer(DecryptedText[0], Length(DecryptedText));
    OutputStream.SaveToFile('Z:\_OUT\Dump\d.txt');
  finally
    AES.Free;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure Test;
var
  Key: TBytes;
  IV: TBytes;
  PlainStream, EncryptedStream, DecryptedStream: TMemoryStream;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Задание ключа и IV явно
  Key := TBytes.Create($00, $01, $02, $03, $04, $05, $06, $07, $08, $09, $0A, $0B, $0C, $0D, $0E, $0F,
                       $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $1A, $1B, $1C, $1D, $1E, $1F); // 256 бит
  IV := TBytes.Create($00, $01, $02, $03, $04, $05, $06, $07, $08, $09, $0A, $0B, $0C, $0D, $0E, $0F); // 128 бит
  // Создание потоков
  PlainStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  EncryptedStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  DecryptedStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // Запись данных в исходный поток
    PlainStream.WriteBuffer(TBytes.Create(72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33)[0], 13); // "Hello, World!"
    // Шифрование
    EncryptStream(PlainStream, EncryptedStream, Key, IV);
    // Расшифровка
    DecryptStream(EncryptedStream, DecryptedStream, Key, IV);
    // Вывод расшифрованных данных
    DecryptedStream.Position := 0;
    for i := 0 to DecryptedStream.Size - 1 do
      Write(Char(PByte(DecryptedStream.Memory)[i]));
    Writeln;
  finally
    PlainStream.Free;
    EncryptedStream.Free;
    DecryptedStream.Free;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Executing of the program each time gives a different ciphertext, and if the key and initialization vector (IV) are specified explicitly in the code and do not change, then there is a clear contradiction with the basic properties of AES in OFB (Output Feedback Mode) mode. In OFB mode, when using the same keys and IV (initialization vector), the result of encrypting the same string should be the same.

Constructor TAESOFB takes aKey as untyped parameter:
constructor TAESAbstractEncryptOnly.Create(const aKey; aKeySize: cardinal);
begin
  inherited Create(aKey,aKeySize);
  EncryptInit; // as expected by overriden Encrypt/Decrypt methods below
end;

In such cases, if you are dealing with a dynamic array, you must pass a Key[0] (value) to the constructor, not a Key (pointer):
AES := TAESOFB.Create(Key[0], Length(Key) * 8);


Nope. Old version of SynCrypto had some issues. Mormot2 works as expected. Thanks.

@Zhe Not true. I tested your code with latest mormot 1.18.7649. When you pass Key you got a garbage in the fKey: https://i.imgur.com/KIrJ12G.png

@Zhe How to pass dynamic array as untyped const?
